# Salesforce Picklist order

Tags: salesforce

In salesforce, I need to create multi-select picklist field in Account. But as per my use case, I need to mark FIRST selected item from picklist as default.

Can we set the order of selected items from picklist?

If not how we can set as one of the value as FIRST from selected picklist items?

Any ponter will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to set up a preference list, so they can make their choices AND set the preference, or is FIRST one of the options, which should be default and at the top of the list?

Comment: yes, I am trying to set the preference list in salesforce. Can you help me out in this?

Comment: My understanding is that multi-select lists are stored in a semicolon delineated text field, and they are always in the order of the master list, but only include the selected items.  I believe you will need to write functionality to mirror the logic they use in custom views for included columns.

Answer (score 0):

While creating Multi picklist on Account Object make sure you 
checked this checkbox.

**first value as default value**